# Sum of average in Spotfire calculated column

Tags: spotfire

I am averaging a calculated `column` to show on a `visualisation` but my results are not what I want.

```
Exploration wells   Discoveries made
0.10                   0
0.87                   0.32
0.51                   0
0.35                   0
0.51                   0
```

I am calculating the success rate using a simple expression

```
[Discoveries made] / [Exploration Wells]
```

But when I use the `Avg` aggregate in the visual `Spotfire` averages the Expression row by row rather than taking the average of the sum (for each year lets say)

So instead of getting `13.5%` I get `7.4%` 
Is there a workaround for this one?

**Thanks.**

[Here's my summary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZT7f.png)

[image]

I am looking to get the division of the sums for[Discoveries (net)] and [Exploration Wells (net), which for this year would be 2.65/7.71=0.34

Instead I am getting 0.29

**My raw data table looks like that:**

[image]

That's because Spotfire calculates the division on a row by row basis and provides me with the Avg of the calculated column (0.29)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @Mourst- The screenshots posted are incomplete to understand the issue. Could you post a screenshot of the visualization based on this data and highlight the issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Mourst- I calculated success rate which is `[Discoveries] / [Exploration Wells]` with the raw data provided. I am getting 0.34.

Not sure as why you are getting 0.29. Could you post more details as how you are calculating?

**Here are the output tables:**

[image]

Comment: The issue when I try to chart this I am getting the 0.29.Using the line chart as an example, I have to pick an aggregate function for the axis I plot the Success Rate.Picking Avg gives me back 0.29.I can't really work it out.Thanks

Comment: @Mourst- Could you post that chart?

Comment: @ksp585-Once again the solution was simpler than I thought. Instead of calculating a new column from the Sum of the [Discoveries] and [Exploration Wells], I used a custom expression on the value axis to do it on the fly instead. That's now sorted.Thanks

Comment: @ksp585-Got another question if you can help me with. I used this expression to plot my data correctly : Sum([Discoveries (net)]) / Sum([Exploration Wells (net)]) as [Total Success Rate], Sum([Commercial Discoveries (net)]) / Sum([Exploration Wells (net)]) as [Commercial Success Rate]. Do you know if I can somehow replace empty cells with "NA" or something like that? Can't really work it out on the show/hide tab.Thanks